# Calling exec() inside a signal-handler to reload currently running process

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals

Is the behavior defined for the scenario when an exec() is called from within a signal-handler for the current process? -- for example, having a `SIGHUP` handler that calls exec() for the same binary as of the currently running process to reload itself.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it would be a problem. It completely replaces the current process, so any interrupted state is irrelevant.

Comment: For the above mentioned scenario, I notice the process cannot listen to the SIGHUP more than once. I am suspicious that the new exec is utilizing the signal stack and so later cannot listen to the signals anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the behavior is defined and safe.

The `exec*` family of functions — but notably *excluding* the "path" variants `execlp` and `execvp` — are async-signal-safe per the treatment of [Signal Actions in § 2.4.3](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03) in POSIX.1-2017.